# Lenovo Update failed. Stuck in recovery

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, boot-loop, lenovo, lenovo-a6000-plus

Today my Lenovo A6000plus said there is an update to download, and I clicked it. It was a 9MB download. Download went fine, and to update it restarted to recovery. I think there is some error in the downloaded update. It is now stuck in recovery mode. I tried wiped cache, and factory resetted it through recovery, Still no change. It was rooted, but no CWM installed.  What should I do?
Urgently need help.
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide additional info, do any errors messages appear? When you format it, does it say it was successful? Did it show the 'Updating Apps' screen when you updated it?

Comment: Sorry, I panicked. I left my mobile to update and when I came back it was in Recovery, I thought it was normal, so I rebooted it from the menu. and No, the Updating apps didn't showed.

Comment: Does it show up in adb if you connect it to a PC?

Comment: Actually I dont know to connect via adb. So I didn't checked. Sorry again

Comment: And I would suggest flashing the default ROM to it

Comment: That is the problem. I got hold of a link to stock rom. but the instructions said that I need CWM installed.  I have flashed Galaxy S2 with Odin. Is it the same procedure?

Comment: If it says 'Apply Update from external storage' in the Android System Recovery Screen, then its possible to restore your tablet, but you could end up having your tablet bricked.

Comment: K, I'll try that... thx